# Power bi advanced editor

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to update a column in my table before loading it.
Is it possible to do this in the advanced editor in power bi using similar statements to sql join , update, ..
What i need to do is update 1 column with the value of another column based on a join condition with the same table.

Comment: What do you try already?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear - do you just want to lookup a value from a different table?

If so, you could use the `LOOKUPVALUE` function

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492170.aspx